# Can I invoke a class method from an ActiveRecord::Concern without mixing it into another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

I'm creating an [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) that defines several class methods using the [`class_methods`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-class_methods) method. With a regular module it is possible to invoke the class methods directly using `NameOfModule.target_method` (e.g. in the stdlib class Math it's common to invoke [acos](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Math.html#method-c-acos) like so `Math.acos(x)`) but I'm at a loss finding how to perform a similar invocation my `Concern`. Is this possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't because the methods defined in the block of `class_methods` are actually defined in the module `Foo::ClassMethods` (`Foo` is your concern). Here is the relevant source code of `ActiveSupport::Concern`

```
module ActiveSupport
  # ...
  module Concern
    # ...
    def class_methods(&class_methods_module_definition)
      mod = const_defined?(:ClassMethods, false) ?
        const_get(:ClassMethods) :
        const_set(:ClassMethods, Module.new)

      mod.module_eval(&class_methods_module_definition)
    end
  end
end
```

You can see that `class_methods` just creates the module `ClassMethods` for you if it is not defined by yourself. The methods you defined are just instance methods in that module, so you can't call it at the module level.

Later on, the module `ClassMethods` will be extended by the class that includes your concern. Here is the relevant source code:

```
module ActiveSupport
  # ...
  module Concern
    def append_features(base)
      if base.instance_variable_defined?(:@_dependencies)
        # ...
      else
        # ...
        base.extend const_get(:ClassMethods) if const_defined?(:ClassMethods)  # <-- Notice this line
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! So in practice to test a concern's class methods you must always use a class where the concern is included.